# JS inject with template and regex

Tags: javascript, html, code-injection

On [this page](http://escape.alf.nu/10/) it suggest the code below is injectable. However I don't see how. An answer online says putting this `\74a onclick=alert(1)\76W` into the textarea (below name) labeled "Input" and clicking W is the solution.

The page indeed says I win however I think it's wrong

I [ran it on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lj7v4) and found it was properly escaped and wasn't injected. What is the page saying? Is there really an injection or is the challenge page wrong?

HTML:

```
<div id="c">text</div>
```

JS:

```
//from challenge page
function escape(s) {
  function htmlEscape(s) {
    return s.replace(/./g, function(x) {
       return { '<': '&lt;', '>': '&gt;', '&': '&amp;', '"': '&quot;', "'": '&#39;' }[x] || x;       
     });
  }

  function expandTemplate(template, args) {
    return template.replace(
        /{(\w+)}/g, 
        function(_, n) { 
           return htmlEscape(args[n]);
         });
  }

  return expandTemplate(
    "                                                \n\
      <h2>Hello, <span id=name></span>!</h2>         \n\
      <script>                                       \n\
         var v = document.getElementById('name');    \n\
         v.innerHTML = '<a href=#>{name}</a>';       \n\
      <\/script>                                     \n\
    ",
    { name : s }
  );
}

//the solution 
$('#c').html(escape('\74a onclick=alert(1)\76W'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the backslashes so that `\74` and `\76` reach the escape function unchanged. Otherwise they're converted to `<` and `>` too early.

```
$('#c').html(escape('\\74a onclick=alert(1)\\76W'));
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Lj7v4/1/